# How to maintain page state across refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to make a web page that can keep its state when refreshed by the user.

Multiple answers on this site suggest storing the state in the browser's local storage. This works fine. Sort of. However, when the user opens the same page in multiple tabs and refreshes one of them, the state gets restored from a different tab. Not good.

Another approach is to put the state into a form input. In Firefox, the state of form inputs is preserved across refresh, although some consider it [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654072). Unfortunately, not everyone uses Firefox.

So I tried to use `history` API. Here is what I tried:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test</title>
<input placeholder="Input state">
<script>
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
    input.value = history.state
    console.log("Loaded state", history.state)
    window.onunload = function() {
        history.replaceState(input.value, "")
        console.log("Saved state", history.state)
    }
</script>
```

When the page is unloaded, it uses `history.replaceState()` to store the state. When loading, it reads `history.state`. Should work, right?

Well, it works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. In Chrome, when reading `history.state` in `unload` handler, the correct value is returned, but after the page is refreshed, the value reverts to `null`. Isn't it supposed to be preserved?

It it possible to preserve the state using `history` in Chrome? Are there other good ways to achieve this? I know it's possible to store the state in the URL (using `history.replaceState()` or `location.hash`), but it is visible to the user, and it probably won't work very well if the state is big. There is also `window.name`, but it leaks to other pages.

Comment: `sessionStorage`. Works like `localeStorage`. But for each tab..

Comment: What about cookies?

Comment: `sessionStorage` doesn't work in Chrome for `file:` URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If you can store the state in localStorage and can know that the state of a different tab got updated in a tab, can you not store the state as a map where the key is the (generated unique) name of the tab and the value is the state of that tab?

Comment: So, after a refresh, how would a tab know its name?

Comment: I had written, "If you can know that the state of a different tab got updated in a tab". So if the answer is yes, then you do have some mechanism to differentiate between the tabs. Right?

Comment: Otherwise consider this (I am just thinking out loud): If you do not have the name as an input parameter to the page, you create a name, delete the history of the current page (from browser history) and reload the page with the (unique) name you made up. make sure it is unique by looking up the local storage.